# How to get begininng of day and end of day in javascript date?

Tags: javascript

How to get start of day in .toDate() format T00:00 and T11:59:59?
Everytime I get start of Day and add toDate() it adds 7 hours to the date
Thanks

Comment: Some date methods use UTC and some use local time zone. There's basically no way to know in advance, you need to look it up in documentation.

Comment: could it be because of timezone? in plain js you can see that with .getTimezoneOffset() and using moment.js has https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

Comment: Oh my mongodb is storing in UTC hours. so i have to do setUTCHours in my node js?

Answer (score 0):

`new Date('2021-08-26T00:00')` will give you the start of the given date in your default timezone.

`new Date('2021-08-26T00:00Z')` will give you the start of the given date in UTC.

`new Date('2021-08-26T23:59:59.999')` will give you the end of the given date in your default timezone. While you could just add 86399999 milliseconds to the first date, this would give the wrong result on days when Daylight Saving Time starts and ends.

To get the start and end of the current date this way for the default local timezone, you can do this:

```
const now = new Date();
// JavaScript only outputs ISO format as UTC,
//   so a timezone adjust trick is needed.
const todayIso = new Date(now.getTime() - now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000).toISOString().substr(0, 10);
const startOfDay = new Date(todayIso + 'T00:00');
const endOfDay = new Date(todayIso + 'T25:59:59.999');
```

Answer (score -2):

Use Moment or date-fns methods to achieve

Comment: What is it with everyone and suggesting Moment for just about every date-related JavaScript issue in StackOverflow?

Comment: Moment is mutable library. Better to go with date-fns.

Comment: I got the point but incase of something specific for user requirements, one can always use part of library which can help quickly, rather than re-inventing the wheel .

Comment: Moment is not the universal solution to date problems, esp. when it's often initialised with already mangled `Date` objects.